# Static css is not implementing in django templates

Tags: python, html, css, django

I made this project for my own learning about 2 months back. That time all things were working properly . After that today, I again ran this project but this time static css is not being applied on templates. I could not find any issue. Please help me with this.

[This is the folder outlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMLjt.jpg)

[This is the setting code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spJYk.jpg)

[This is base template code that is extended in other html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j41tk.jpg)

Comment: It's better you share code not upload photo of it. Otherwise, you will get negative voting on your question

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,for%20users%20with%20visual%20impairments.

Comment: Ok i will keep that i mind next time

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can try this way:

```
<link href="{% static './css/style.css' %}" /> #look closely i have added ./ before css.
```

And see if it solves your problem

Comment: I tried  but it didn't work.